# How to associate IDLE 3.6.2 with Python 3.6.2 in CentOS 7

Tags: python, centos

`CentOS 7` comes with `Python2.7.5`

I installed `Python 3.6.2`, and was able to launch IDLE 3.6.2 in terminal by typing `IDLE 3.6.2`.

However, when I run using F5, I am still getting `Python 2.7.5` instead of `python 3.6.2.`

I tried doing

```
./configure

make altinstall
```

didnt resolve the issue. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands:

- `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`
- `yum -y install yum-utils yum-builddep python zlib-devel gcc`
- `cd /usr/src`
- `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.2/Python-3.6.2rc1.tgz`
- `tar xzf Python-3.6.2rc1.tgz`
- `cd Python-3.6.2rc1/`
- `./configure`
- `make`
- `make install`
- `which python3 && python3 -V`

Comment: I tried the above but it still does not work. I have been installing multiple versions on CentOS.Do you think if I should uninstall all the version first?

Comment: Try a clean uninstall first and then do what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using [Inline with Upstream Stable](https://ius.io/) is the easiest to get Python 3.6 on Centos machines. Here is the full tutorial I found on the subject: [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-centos-7).

Depending on your needs, alternative solution could be to use Anaconda distribution that doesn't require root to be installed. (sorry for lack of link but I am limited to post only two, it is easy to google though).